# Can't mongoDB insert in promises function js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm actually building a simple application in meteor that's taking a weapon's skin thought my steam inventory, parse the weapon's market hash name, and finally return the median price of the skin according to the steam market. My problem is about storing the price of the skin, I use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csgo-market) npm package that I have included in Meteor (I followed the asynchronous way) and I can easily get the skin's price. I put this code into a Meteor method on the server-side, like this :

```
Meteor.methods({

getPrice:function(weapon,skin,state,loteryRef)
{
      
  
    var csgomarket = Meteor.npmRequire('csgo-market');

    var Q = Meteor.npmRequire('q');
  
    var wears = [state];

    var data = {
      prices : [{
        weapon : weapon,
        cached : false,
        skins : [skin],
        skinData : {},
        price : '',
      }]
    }
  
    var getPrice = function(theData) {
      var promises = [];
      theData.skins.forEach(function(skin) {
        theData.skinData[skin] = {};
        wears.forEach(function(wear) {
          promises.push(csgomarket.getSinglePriceAsync(theData.weapon, skin, wear, false).then(function(data) {
          
            theData.price = data.median_price;
             
          }));
        });
      });
      return Q.allSettled(promises).then(function() {
        return theData;
      });
    }

    getPrice(data.prices[0]).then(function(results) {
       
            console.log(results.price);
            
    });
    
            
}
});
```

The result of the promise's function `getPrice(data.prices[0]).then(function(results) {});` can only be console.logged and I can't save results outside of this function. When I try to perform an insert in this function for saving this value, it doesn't work too. What I'm doing wrong ?

Please forgive me for my quite good English

Comment: sure, mongoDB is currently included in the default set of meteor-platform packages, so the only information that I can provide you about mongo is the version (2.6.7). About the insert inside of my getPrice() methode, I just perform a simple insert like :
Lotery.insert({
started :  new Date().getTime(),
reference : loteryRef,
type: 1,
end : false,
max: 10,
item_price: results.price,
});